A polynomial $P$ of degree $2015$ satisfies the equation $P(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots, 2016$. Find $2017P(2017)$.

A polynomial $P$ of degree $2015$ satisfies the equation $P(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots, 2016$. Find $2017P(2017)$.

My try :
Let $$x^2P(x) - 1 = (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2016)(ax+b).$$
Since $P$ is a polynomial it must be defined for $x = 0$, so $-1 = 2016!(b)$ so $b = -\frac{1}{2016!}$
Therefore, $$x^2P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2016)\left(ax - \frac{1}{2016!}\right) + 1$$
So, $$2017^2P(2017) = (2017-1)(2017-2)\cdots(2017-2016)\left(2017a- \frac{1}{2016!}\right) + 1 = 2017a$$
Therefore $2017P(2017) = a$.
How to proceed from here or any way to prove the polynomial is monic ?

Two possible lines of attack occur to me: A) instead of $2016$ use $n=3$, $n=4$ etc as the parameter to see how the land lies. B) Differentiate both sides of
$$x^2P(x)-1=(x-1)\cdots(x-2016)(ax+b)$$
and then plug in $x=0$. Don't know about any insights either line could give. I haven't checked.

This could easily be from some old contest. If so, then [tag:contest-math] is an appropriate tag.

Maybe try induction (possibly splitting by even/odd)? If we replace $2015$ by $1$, we get $P(1) = 1, P(2) = 1/4$, so $P(3) = -1/2$ and $3P(3) = -3/2$. Replacing it by $4$ gives $4P(4) = 7/3$. Can you develop from there?

@BrianTung but how can we replace something already known ? Also in such questions mostly it's given that the polynomial is monic but here's not the case , if we might prove its monic too might work

The point is that there likely isn't anything special about $2015$ in this regard. That is, one might try to derive an expression for $(n+2)P(n+2)$ for $P$ an $n$th-degree polynomial such that $P(k) = 1/k^2$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n+1$. ETA: The polynomial is probably not monic.

From $x^2P(x)=(x-1)\ldots$, the linear coefficient of the right hand side has to be $0$ so that $P$ is a polynomial. This determines $a$ via a lengthy calculation.

I got (basically with approach B, or just expanding it like @anankElpis) that
$$a=H_{2016}/(2016!),$$
where $H_n$ stands for the partial sum of the harmonic series
$$H_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.$$ This does not simplify (because its value grows like $\ln n$). Needs to be checked for sign errors as well as off-by-one -errors :-)

@Ash_Blanc FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread 2017 Algebra/NT #6: Polynomial of Degree 2015. There's also the similar Mock Mathcounts 2015, which deals with degree $18$, and ...

(cont.) Let P be a polynomial of degree n such that P(k) = 1/k^2,, which deals with more generally with polynomials of degree $n$.

Let $\mathcal P(n)=n^2P(n)-1$. Then, $\mathcal P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $2017$, and has the zeros $n=1,2,3,\ldots,2016$ that satisfy $P(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Let $a$ and $r$ be the leading coefficient and the remaining zero of the polynomial $\mathcal P(n)$ respectively. Then, we can write: $\mathcal P(n)=n^2P(n)-1=a(n-r)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-2016)$.
We have,
$$n^2P(n)=a(n-r)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-2016)+1\tag{1}$$
The constant term and the coefficient of $n$ on RHS of $(1)$ must vanish. So, constant term$=-ar\cdot2016!+1=0\implies\color{red}{ ar\cdot2016!=1}$.
Similarly, the coefficient of $n=0$, i.e., $$\begin{aligned}&a\left(\frac{r\cdot2016!}{r}+\frac{r\cdot2016!}{1}+\frac{r\cdot2016!}{2}+\frac{r\cdot2016!}{3}+\ldots+\frac{r\cdot2016!}{2016}\right)=0\\&\implies a\cdot2016!+\color{red}{ar\cdot2016!}\cdot H_{2016}=0\\&\color{red}{\implies a\cdot2016!=-H_{2016}}
\end{aligned}$$
where $H_{2016}=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac{1}{2016}\right)$ is called the $2016$th harmonic number.
Now, substitute $n=2017$ in $(1)$. We get
$$2017^2P(2017)=a(2017-r)\cdot2016!+1=a\cdot2017!-ar\cdot2016!+1=a\cdot2017!$$
i.e.,
$$\color{red}{\boxed{2017P(2017)=a\cdot2016!=-H_{2016}\approx-8.1863342895}}$$

You have $$x^2P(x)=a(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2016)(x-c)+1$$
Since $P(x)$ is a polynomial $x^2$ must be a factor of RHS which implies constant term and coefficient of $x$ must be $0$
Constant term
$$
1-ac(2016!)=0\implies ac=\frac1{2016!}
$$
x term
$$
(2016!)ac\left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{2016}+\frac1c\right)=0
$$
Since $ac\neq0$ $$\left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{2016}+\frac1c\right)=0$$
Solving for $c,a$ we get that its not monic
